# Complex models and data binding ASP.NET Core 5 issue

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am using ASP.NET Core 5 with a complex model and I am having a heck of a time getting the model to post correctly.

Here is my model class:

```
public class Project
{
        [Key]
        public int ProjectId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        
        public virtual List<ResponsibleParty> ResponsibleParties { get; set; }
        public virtual List<ProjectManager> ProjectManagers { get; set; }
}
```

In my razor page I am doing the following:

```
[BindProperty]
public Project Project { get; set; }

[BindProperty]
public ResponsibleParty ResponsibleParty { get; set; }
```

I am using a bootstrap model to popup a window that allows the user to enter the information for `ResponibleParty` and an "Add" button that posts back where I add the `ResponsibleParty` to the `Project.ResponsibleParty` list. On the page returns I can see the `ResponsibleParty` was added and displayed.

Now.. when I try to add another and the page posts the project model no longer contains the `ResponsibleParty`.

Any ideas here on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> I am using a bootstrap model to popup a window that allows the user to
> enter the information for ResponibleParty and an Add button that posts
> back where I add the ResponsibleParty to the Project.ResponsibleParty
> List. One the page returns I can see the ResponsibleParty was added
> and displayed. Now.. When I try to add another and the Page Posts the
> Project model no longer contains the ResponsibleParty. Any Ideas here
> on what I'm doing wrong?

Please check your Post method, whether the new item is inserted successfully, and in the get method, whether you are getting the latest data.

Based on the model and your description, I create a sample and use session to store the Project data, you can refer to them:

1. Configure the application to use session, and add the SessionExtensions class to store object. Refer this article: [Configure session state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-5.0#configure-session-state)

   [Note] Please note the session expired time. Besides, if you don't want to use the session, you can also store the data into database.
2. Create model:

   ```
    public class Project
    {
        [Key]
        public int ProjectId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual List<ResponsibleParty> ResponsibleParties { get; set; }

        public virtual List<ProjectManager> ProjectManagers { get; set; }
    }

    public class ResponsibleParty
    {
        public int ResponsiblePartyId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class ProjectManager {
        public int PMid { get; set; }
        public string PMName { get; set; }
    }
   ```
3. Create a ProjectIndex Razor Page:

   ProjectIndex.cshtml:

   ```
    @page "/projectIndex"
    @model RazorWebApplication.Pages.ProjectIndexModel
    @{
        ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
    }

    <h2>Project Index</h2>
    <div class="container">
        @if (Model.Project != null && Model.Project.ResponsibleParties.Count > 0)
        {
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            ProjectId
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Name
                        </th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var item in Model.Project.ResponsibleParties)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ResponsiblePartyId)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.ResponsiblePartyId">Edit</a> |
                                <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.ResponsiblePartyId">Details</a> |
                                <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.ResponsiblePartyId">Delete</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>

        }

    </div>


    <!-- Button to Open the Modal -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
        Create New ResponsibleParty
    </button>

    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div class="modal" id="myModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <form method="post" asp-page-handler="AddResponsibleParty">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="row p-5 border pt-4 my-3 rounded">
                            <div class="input-group row mb-3">
                                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 d-sm-block">
                                    <label asp-for="ResponsibleParty.ResponsiblePartyId"></label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12"> 
                                    <textarea class="form-control" asp-for="ResponsibleParty.ResponsiblePartyId"></textarea>
                                    <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="ResponsibleParty.ResponsiblePartyId"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-group row mb-3">
                                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 d-sm-block">
                                    <label asp-for="ResponsibleParty.Name"></label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12"> 
                                    <textarea class="form-control" asp-for="ResponsibleParty.Name"></textarea>
                                    <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="ResponsibleParty.Name"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-group row mb-3">
                                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   ```

   ProjectIndex.cshtml.cs:

   ```
    public class ProjectIndexModel : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty]
        public Project Project { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        public ResponsibleParty ResponsibleParty { get; set; }

        private readonly string sessionkeyproject = "project";
        public void OnGet()
        { 
            //check if the seesion is null. 
            if (HttpContext.Session.Get<Project>(sessionkeyproject) == default)
            {
                //if session is null, set the initial data.
                Project = new Project()
                {
                    ProjectId = 101,
                    Name = "A",
                    ResponsibleParties = new List<ResponsibleParty>()
                 {
                      new ResponsibleParty(){ ResponsiblePartyId=1001, Name="RP1"},
                      new ResponsibleParty(){ ResponsiblePartyId=1002, Name="RP2"},
                 }
                };
                //store the data using session
                HttpContext.Session.Set<Project>(sessionkeyproject, Project);
            }
            else
            {
                // get the latest data from the session.
                Project = HttpContext.Session.Get<Project>(sessionkeyproject);
            }
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAddResponsibleParty()
        {
            var newitem = ResponsibleParty;

            if (HttpContext.Session.Get<Project>(sessionkeyproject) == default)
            {
                return RedirectToPage();
            }
            else
            {
                //get the project from the session
                Project = HttpContext.Session.Get<Project>(sessionkeyproject);
            }

            //add the new responsibleparty into the project
            Project.ResponsibleParties.Add(new ResponsibleParty()
            {
                ResponsiblePartyId = newitem.ResponsiblePartyId,
                Name = newitem.Name
            });

            //update the seesion to store the latest data.
            HttpContext.Session.Set<Project>(sessionkeyproject, Project);

            return RedirectToPage();//still to decide where it should go
        }
    }
   ```

The result as below:

[image]